# Does Redmine have the facility for custom fields whose values are restricted to those of the project when creating issues?

Tags: projects, redmine, custom-fields

Is it possible to add custom fields useable for all projects, but have the values linked with the project, so that when creating issues the dropdown list shows only the values which have been used for that project, like the target version which is linked with a project?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve - please be more explicit, add examples, tell us what version control system you use, etc... The title _How does redmine offer a way to filter custom fields by project ?_ makes my head hurt when I try to understand what that could possibly mean.

Comment: @marapet eg a project allows you to add target versions, and when you are adding issues you can choose the target version or even add new targets versions to the project. They are also added from a list so you can't type anything you want.

What I want to know is if you can have a custom field like the target version whose choices are limited to the project, like its branches

Comment: ok I get it now, I don't think this is possible, however maybe there is a plugin ? Otherwise, if the values are different for each project, why not a different custom field for each project?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet implemented in Redmine.

My solution will be to prefix the branch name with a short code for the project and that way the field can be used for all projects, eg PROJABBREVIATION_branchA. Hopefully the prefixes won't be too awkward.